# How to lock particular customer account in Magento 2

Tags: customer-account

I want to lock particular customer account in magento store. Any options to lock or blacklisted customer account using admin panel

Answer (score 5):

Instead of making a module or having to recode anything, I did it through phpmyadmin. When you go in your files, go to **customer_entity**

Go to the customer that you want to LOCK out of their account. Click edit and go to the part that says

> failures_num

and I typed 10 because max failed attempts is only 3.
Go down to

> lock_expires

and use the calendar to choose the year you want the lock to expire. You have to be within a reasonable time for it to accept the date, like 10 years from now. 
**SAVE**

Then go to 
**customer_grid_flat**
go down to

> lock_expires

and put the same date as you did the other file. **SAVE**

**DONE**

Now the customer can't log in until you unlock it. Which if you choose to, you can do in the admin panel under their customer info. 
[image: Customer Side]

---

[image: Admin Side]

Comment: Thanks. One issue I ran into is the Year2038 Problem ... I tried to set the locked date to 9999 and 2099, but only until 2038 works, because our Datetime Fields seem to be 32Bit

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do it from the admin panel, but you can set a value to the `lock_expires` field in the table `customer_entity` to a date really far in the future. This should lockout the customer.